# Angular reference misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I've just realized, I don't quite get scoping in Angular. Take a closer look at `var Cart`: I tried to access `cartItems` variable just like `cartItems: cartItems` and that doesn't work. And if I wrap it into function, I get this variable from the closure (as chrome dev tools say). Could someone explain me the difference and why can't I access `cartItems` straight away from the `Cart` object? Thanks.

P.S. Tried to use `this` instead of `var` for variables, makes no difference.

```
.factory('Cart', function(FirebaseUrl, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $state, Auth) {

    var cartsRef = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl + '/carts');
    var userId, cartRef, cartItems;

    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) { // triggers on entering the page
      userId = authData && authData.uid;
      cartRef = new Firebase(cartsRef + '/' + userId);
      cartItems = $firebaseArray(cartRef);
    });

    var Cart = {
      getCartItems: function() {
        return cartItems;
      },
      cartItems: cartItems // this won't work
    };  

    return Cart;
  });
```

**EDIT:** to grant understanding to my question, I'll provide a chunk of controller code:

```
 .controller('CartCtrl', function(Cart, Auth) {
    var cartCtrl = this;
    cartCtrl.cartItems = Cart.getCartItems(); // returns items
    cartCtrl.cartItems1 = Cart.cartItems; // returns undefined. Why?
```

Comment: How / from where are you trying to access the `cartItems` ? The code you provided isn't a controller but a factory, so I don't see what this has to do with angular scopes or the controller as syntax

Comment: from `var userId, cartRef, cartItems;`, where I define the variable, and in `Auth.$onAuth` you can see `cartItems = $firebaseArray(cartRef);`

Comment: and I mean not `$scope`, but just JS scope.

Comment: @Aaron edited question. Maybe this would make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `cartItems: cartItems`, you're assigning that property to the **current value** of `cartItems` - which is nothing!

When you do `getCartItems: function () ....`, you're not accessing `cartItems` until a later point in time -- when the function becomes called. Only at that point, when it is called, are you accessing the **value** of `cartItems`, which has been set.

What you're looking at isn't quite `$scope`, or JS scope, it's references. You're making a "by value" assignment, which is different during these two different points in time.

Here's a simple example:

```
var foo = 'foo';

var fooAsValue = foo;

function fooAsFunction () {
  return foo;
}

foo = 'bar';

console.log(fooAsValue) // "foo"
console.log(fooAsFunction()) // "bar"
```

As you can see, when you assign `fooAsValue` to `foo`, you're getting the value from that point in time -- `'foo'`.

When you change `foo`, the other variable, `fooAsValue`, has already captured its value from before -- that doesn't change. When you execute `fooAsFunction`, after assigning it to `'bar'`, you receive that new value because you're referencing the variable now that it has the new value.

---

If it were **an object reference**, this would be different and it'd be **more like a pointer**.

Let's look at this example:

```
var anObject = {
  foo: {bar: 'foobar'}
};

var fooAsReference = anObject.foo;

anObject.foo.bar = 'hello world';

console.log(fooAsReference) // {bar: 'hello world'}
```

This is where things change a little. The assignment is being made to an object's property, which points to another object.

Here we point to `anObject.foo`, and we change `anObject.foo.bar`, we actually retain the original reference because that didn't change -- the change happened further down the object tree. We see that change because our reference didn't change. What changed was a value *inside* the object we reference, rather than the value we're pointing to.

This is all a little tricky, but if you get hands-on with these two different scenarios, even if it's just a blank file with a couple variables and some console outputs, it'll start to really click.

---

So to bring it all back together,

`cartItems: cartItems` makes an assignment to `cartItems`, which does not yet have a value. So this will be empty.

`getCartItems` returns `cartItems`, which likely has a value by the time you call it. That's because `Auth.$onAuth` has fired, and the assignment `cartItems = $firebaseArray(cartRef);` has been made. *Then* you end up calling the function `getCartItems` *after* that assignment, and then you have the value.

### What you can do

```
var Cart = {cartItems: []};

Auth.$onAuth(function () {
  // ...
  // Now we're talkin!
  Cart.cartItems = $firebaseArray(cartRef);
});

return Cart;
```

Instead of having `Cart.cartItems` pointing to something we know can change, we can move the single source of truth to being `Cart.cartItems` itself. Update that property, rather than a separate variable.

Could also simplify the naming to simply be `Cart.items`, since we already know "these items belong to the cart" :)

Comment: Thanks for the broad answer! I think I got it :)

Comment: I made a slight mistake in my second example, will update though :)

Comment: Updated a second time with a potential solution to your specific problem

Comment: Yes, I think this solution is better. Thanks once again !